# RDLC - Multivalue param missing value

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, reportingservices-2005, report-viewer2010

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bwelcker/archive/2007/07/11/laser-guided-missiles-report-localization-through-parameters.aspx

I am trying to implement this in **WinForms**.

I am getting an error that  the multi valued parameter is not provided a value.

What I have done is I have a Dataset by name ResourceDictionary and I am using that in the "Available Value" for my multivalue param - ResourceParam.

Then for translation, I am using the expreession - =Code.GetLabel(Parameters!ResourceParam,Fields!TransactionType.Value)

Appreciate all help. Thanks

```
  reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath & "Expense.rdlc"
  expenseList = ReportManager.GetExpenseReport(Application.AppDatabase, Application.FirmID, FromDate, ToDate, dtFormat, True, Application.AppResources)
  Dim reportDataSource1 As New ReportDataSource()
            reportDataSource1.Name = "ExpenseList"
            reportDataSource1.Value = expenseList
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1)
            'reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource With {.Name = "ResourceDictionary", .Value = res})
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Header1", UIHelper.GetRsxVal("date"), True))
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Header2", UIHelper.GetRsxVal("expensetype"), True))
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Header3", UIHelper.GetRsxVal("refno"), True))
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Header4", UIHelper.GetRsxVal("totalamt"), True))
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Header5", "", True))
            paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportHeader", UIHelper.GetRsxVal("expensehdr"), True))
         reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList)
        reportViewer.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970058) article here that explains the error you described above and it's possible workarounds. The one that seems to be most straightforward is to set an rs param as follows:

Enable cookie sessions by specifying `rs:ClearSession=true` in the URL for the report

Comment: I am using Windows Forms. I guess session is not applicable then.

Comment: The forms don't use session, however, that setting is a command for the webservice api that does establish sessions.

Comment: I am pretty sure these can be set on the ReportViewer properties.